# Excel Macro to hide rows across multiple sheets

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have a macro that hides rows based on cell values. I am attempting to use this across multiple sheets in the workbook, but not all of them. My code below seems to run the macro multiple times in the same sheet.

```
Sub HideRowsWbk()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ThisWorkbook
    For Each ws In .Worksheets
        Select Case ws.Name
        Case "0000_Index", "000_BidItems", "000_EntrySheet", "000_PayReqs"
             'do nothing - exclude these sheets

        Case Else
            With ws
                LastRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row '
                Set Rng = Range("M15:M" & LastRow) 'choose column where value exists

                For Each cell In Rng
                    If cell.Value = "0" Or cell.Value = "-" Then  'checks if cell value is 0 or -
                        cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    End If
                Next cell
            End With
        End Select
    Next ws
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Please tell me what I have done wrong and how I can fix this. Also please show me how I can improve my minimal coding skills. I am using Excel 2007.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
LastRow = .Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row '
Set Rng = .Range("M15:M" & LastRow) 'choose column where value exists
```

the "**.**"  makes it work with **ws**